# if selected field is blank choose another (Blank, not null. please do not close)

Tags: sql, oracle

For this query I am trying to `select R23VENAD-PLT-ADDR-2`, but if `R23VENAD-PLT-ADDR-2` is blank then I need to grab `R23VENAD-PLT-ADDR-3`, but if this is blank I need to grab `WMS-VENDOR-ADDRESS-L2`.
How can I write this query?

```
SELECT
R23VENAD-PLT-ADDR-2 -- (however, if this field is blank choose R23VENAD-PLT-ADDR-3, if this one is also empty then use WMS-VENDOR-ADDRESS-L2)
.......
```

I was stuck at this. I found only if null, but it is not useful here.

Comment: If all columns have the same datatype (and it seems so in your case), `COALESCE` as mentioned in the answer is clearly the best choice. If not, you can try to use `NVL` instead. If this also doesn't work, you would need to use `CASE WHEN...` or to cast the columns.

Comment: The duplicate gives multiple solutions (just replace the string literal with the second column you want to use as a replacement and then repeat for a third column, nesting functions if they only take 2 arguments).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `COALESCE()` to handle any NULLS ( Oracle docs [COALESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COALESCE.html#GUID-3F9007A7-C0CA-4707-9CBA-1DBF2CDE0C87) )

And `NULLIF()` to handle blank text (Oracle docs [NULLIF](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NULLIF.html))

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF( R23VENAD-PLT-ADDR-2,''), NULLIF(R23VENAD-PLT-ADDR-3,''), NULLIF(WMS-VENDOR-ADDRESS-L2,''))
```

Comment: This is valid only if the space is null, not if its blank.

Comment: @AlfredoHuerta I've updated the answer to handle blanks as well as NULL